# smsmanager is not working in alertdialog

Tags: android, smsmanager

heres my code for what i am doing. I hit a submit button and then an alert box with yes/no shows to confirm and when you hit yes it should send a text and save a pdf version. everything works except the text and it doesn't say that it didn't send either.

```
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(shortinsp.this);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Submit Inspection...");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you are Ready?");

            // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    tvstore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView19);
                    //     result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
                    String ph = (Config.NUMBER);
                    String msg = (tvstore +" short " + result);
                    try {
                        SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(ph, null, msg, null, null);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to send text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    printPDF();

                    // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                    //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            });

            // Setting Negative "NO" Button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                    //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

nothing crashes and the printPDF works as planned. but for some reason the text never happens. i have the permissions right. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: How long is `msg`? If it exceeds the maximum length for a single message in the character set you're using, `sendTextMessage()` will (usually) just fail silently.

Comment: 4 words long so I don't know what the problem is

Comment: Well, about the only ways that'll fail without throwing an Exception is if the message is too long, or the number is wrong, but not empty. Check the number, and maybe give `sendMultipartTextMessage()` a try. If you don't actually have the permission, it should throw a `SecurityException`, but you might want to double-check that, too. You know about runtime permission requests in Marshmallow and above, yeah?